# How to find xpath for html code

Tags: selenium, xpath

How to find xpath for the following code

```
<a onclick='openRecord("cel_payrollprocessingstep", "7ac9f66f-dc66-e511-9f4b-000c29f99044")'>CAM Approves Payroll Changes</a>
```

Comment: <a onclick='openRecord("cel_payrollprocessingstep", "7ac9f66f-dc66-e511-9f4b-000c29f99044")'>CAM Approves Payroll Changes</a>

Comment: This questions lacks a lot. If your above comment is example code, you should edit it into your question.

Answer (score 1):

In case of selenium, there is a better approach - locate the link *by link text*. Example in Java:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("CAM Approves Payroll Changes"));
```

If you insist on using XPath, here is one option:

```
//a[contains(@onclick, 'cel_payrollprocessingstep')]
```